# Tapping the Navigation Marker Doesn't Work in Flutter in iOS

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, ios-navigationview

Tapping the navigation marker does not work in Flutter in iOS but it works in Android.
Whenever anyone taps on the marker with an Android phone the navigation option comes down on the right side. But in the same app someone using iOS, tapping on the marker no navigation button comes up.

I want the navigation option in iOS to come when someone taps on the marker like Android.

Comment: Kindly share your code also.